# Allow for backup AD login for windows authentication ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I work for a company that uses active directory for all computers. Everyone also has a AD user account but this does not mean that they use it all the time. Some users only use them for certain applications. For the most part, all general users just use a generic login out in the work areas.

I am new to MVC and I am trying to learn to do everything the proper way. I currently have an application that was written in JAVA that I need to convert to asp.net mvc. I want to make it so that users who are logged in under the shared username are required to login using their own AD credentials to authenticate and impose as themselves from then on in the application.

From what I can make sense of on google, I will need to make a custom authentication method. If so, maybe someone can graciously point me in the right direction.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on IIS7, a former IIS team member wrote a [very useful blog on combining windows and forms authenticatio](http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/)n.

I have and am currently using this in a production intranet system and the following are my comments on how to setup

1. Unlock the  and  configuration sections before you can use them in web.config:

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication
>   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:windowsAuthentication

2. Register the forms authentication wrapper configuration section in your web.config:

> section name="formsAuthenticationWrapper" type="Mvolo.Modules.FormsAuthConfigurationSection"

3. Replace the built-in Forms Authentication module with the wrapper:

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />

<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="Mvolo.Modules.FormsAuthModule" />
```

4. Set the required settings for the gateway page:

```
<security>

  <!-- Enable IIS Windows authentication for the login page -->

  <authentication>

    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />

    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />

  </authentication>

</security>
```

That should do it.

Comment: I want to mark this as an answer but I am stuff confused by all of this. Sorry. I am a Beginner. If I already activated the anonymous and windows authentication from control panel, do I have to unlock it too? Do you have another detailed link? Apparently I cannot get my verbiage right on google ;)

Comment: add full comments on how to setup